# Openstack. Allocate more ram to guest

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I have setup openstack using this guide: http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/single-installer.guide.html

I am able to create multiple instances with the m1.small flavor which uses 2 GB RAM, but when I try to create an instance with any more ram it fails. 
When I try to create the instance in Horizon it gives the error:

> "Error: Failed to launch instance "test": Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance 39f73c98-0b77-4613-a13d-244c357efb55. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u' File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2039, in _do]."

Looking at the nova-conductor.log I have the error:

> internal error: process exited while connnecting to monitor: Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Cannot allocate memory

I am assuming that I need to allow the virtulization to give each guest more than 2 GB RAM, but I just do not know where to start setting that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the installation installs openstack in LXC, and in that container a VM is created for the compute node using libvirt, and this VM only had 4GB memory.
I was able to expand it using this guide http://earlruby.org/2014/05/increase-a-vms-available-memory-with-virsh/